# Annotate a data point with a graph

Tags: matplotlib, annotations

For the lack of better term, is there a way to annotate a data point with a graph? I include an example of what I am for below[image]

Big black data point with a graph corresponding to it. Note that graph is rotated so its "x" axis (not shown) is perpendicular to the "y" axis of the scatter plot

annotation_box http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html is the closest thing I can find at the moment, but even knowing the proper term for what I want to do, would make my life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, what you need are floating axes that you can place as annotations over your plot. Unfortunately, this is not easily possible in matplotlib, as far I know.

An easy solution would be to just plot the points and graphs in the same axis, with the graphs scaled down and shifted close to the points.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xp = [5, 1, 3]
yp = [2, 1, 4]

# just generate some curves
curves_x = np.array([np.linspace(0, 10, 100)] * 3)
curves_y = sps.gamma.pdf(curves_x[0], [[2], [5], [7]], 1)

plt.scatter(xp, yp, s=50)

for x, y, cx, cy in zip(xp, yp, curves_x, curves_y):
    plt.plot(x + cy / np.max(cy) + 0.1 , y + cx / np.max(cx) - 0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a very simplistic example. The numbers will have to be tuned to look nice with varying scale of the data.